# HTML5 Canvas alternative to Spritely?

Tags: javascript, html

I've used a JQuery library called http://spritely.net/ to create image animations, but performance on mobile devices seems to make JQuery look like a bad option. I'm curious to know if anyone has any good alternatives with just HTML5/JS that could accomplish the same effects, but perhaps a little more mobile friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though personally I have not used to in any mobile application, Createjs is a good option.
http://createjs.com/#!/CreateJS. This is in fact very easy to use framework.

Thre is a nice example of using this framework here.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/02/02/pixelflow-easeljs-canvas-dynamic-graphics-example/

Comment: I am loving what I'm seeing in those demos. Definitely going to have to try CreateJS out. Thanks a lot Unni!!

Comment: @HoldTheLine, Please let me know if it works for you,because I am planning to use it very soon.Cheers!